# Play a video file without saving it

Tags: java, video, vlcj

I have to write a java application which has to play a video. This video isn't saved on file but I have it on a struct (like a FileStreamer) and I can't save it on disk. I tried the vlcj plugin and java native library but from what I understand they both want a file path.
 Thank you for your help !

```
 function createPlayer(FileInputStream media){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Project");
    FullScreenStrategy fullScreenStrategy = new DefaultFullScreenStrategy(frame);
    mediaPlayer = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();
    JPanel  controlsPanel = new PannelCreate(mediap);
    frame.setContentPane(mediaPlayer);
    frame.setLocation(100, 100);
    frame.setSize(1050, 600);
    frame.add(controlsPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

     /* vlcj wants a file path as argument of playMedia, however I don't have a filepath because the video isn't saved on disk but in a variable.*/
    mediaPlayer.getMediaPlayer().playMedia(media);
```

Comment: Show some effort taken to solve this yourself.

Comment: Yeah, you're going to need to show us what you've tried so far, otherwise it is impossible to help. Also, I'm not really certain what you are asking, exactly.

Comment: What do you want me to show you? I can't save the video on disk, so I can't use VLCj like I wanted to initially. My idea was to stream the video with a second thread in order to use VLCj with a HTTP streaming. However this solution isn't efficient nor easy to implement. I can show you the code which doesn't work but I don't see how that can be useful...

Comment: I have added my example code to the question.

Comment: Well, since this library doesn't let you take an output stream and just play it then you're going to have to do it on your own by copying and changing code in the playMedia method that is implemented in the abstract class uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.DefaultMediaPlayer.

Comment: Why is the file coming from an outputstream and not an inputstream?

Comment: @Sanchit I try it but i not have the skills to do. Someone have other idea? (even without vlcj)

Comment: @peeskillet Yes, it's a inputstream my mistake sorry.

Comment: If you want to use vlc, you need to look at the imem module (e.g. "vlc -H | grep imem"). Unfortunately imem is not exposed as an API by LibVLC so you would have to do it all yourself (it's certainly possible, but it's not straightforward). Anyway the real killer is that imem does not support seeking and that is where most people give up...

Comment: @caprica Thank you for your help. So there is no other way than saving the video before playing it?

Comment: Not if you want to use LibVLC (and by extension vlcj). Using the imem command line switches *does* work, but it's quite tricky and like I said before you can't seek. Something else like ffmpeg for Java or Xuggler may work for you.